Recursively setting all .mp4 files name as it title
This script is supposed to copy the file name and set it as the title (EXIF metadata) of the video, I got the ExifTool command to from the Video Stack Exchange, and it worked as expected, but I now have tried to add some stuff to it, but the script doesn't work as expected.
Things its supposed to do,:

Recursively check all the MP4 files for the count.
Update their title based on file name.
Show number of successful and unsuccessful updates.

I have found a Python script on the Video Stack Exchange that supposedly does the things that is supposed to do, but I am trying to do this in a batch file.
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Initialize counters for .mp4 files
set count=0
set total=0
set error_count=0

:: Count the .mp4 files in the directory and subdirectories
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    set /a total+=1
)

:: Print how many .mp4 files are found
echo Found !total! .mp4 files.

:: Process each .mp4 file and update metadata
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    set /a count+=1
    exiftool -overwrite_original "-Title<%%~nf" "%%~f" >nul 2>&1
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo ✅ Updated (!count! / !total!) : %%~nxf
    ) else (
        set /a error_count+=1
        echo ❌ Error (!error_count!) updating: %%~nxf
    )
)

:: Final summary
echo.
echo Metadata update complete.
echo Total files updated: !count!
echo Total errors: !error_count!

pause


How does the script not work as expected? What is wrong?

The script crashes as soon as I open it. Previously, I had a simplified version of the script that worked, but it didn’t indicate that it was updating anything, making it less intuitive. I’ve tried using some AI tools to find a solution, but without success.

Any reason that you can't just look at the exiftool output at the end? It will tell you how many files it updated and how many were unchanged. You can add the -efile option which will save the name of any file where there was an actual error in updating. You don't want to loop exiftool as it's startup time is its biggest performance hit and looping will increase the amount of time processing, especially if there are a large number of files. See Exiftool's Common Mistake #3

What causes the crash are the parentesis inside the if command:
echo ✅ Updated (!count! / !total!)
But you can escape them with caret:
echo ✅ Updated ^(!count! / !total!^)
In the exiftool command I guess there should be an equal sign not a smaller than sign:
exiftool -overwrite_original "-Title=%%~nf" "%%~f" >nul 2>&1

So your batch should look like this:
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Initialize counters for .mp4 files
set count=0
set total=0
set error_count=0

:: Count the .mp4 files in the directory and subdirectories
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    set /a total+=1
)

:: Print how many .mp4 files are found
echo Found !total! .mp4 files.

:: Process each .mp4 file and update metadata
for /r %%f in (*.mp4) do (
    set /a count+=1
    exiftool -overwrite_original "-Title=%%~nf" "%%~f" >nul 2>&1
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo ✅ Updated ^(!count! / !total!^) : %%~nxf
    ) else (
        set /a error_count+=1
        echo ❌ Error ^(!error_count!^) updating: %%~nxf
    )
)

:: Final summary
echo.
echo Metadata update complete.
echo Total files updated: !count!
echo Total errors: !error_count!

pause


Good catch! Exiftool's Common Mistake #5c. The equal sign is used for direct assignment, as it would be in this case. The less than sign is used for copying one tag to another. In the linked answer it is used to copy the Basename tag into the Title tag.
